# Upload Image file with some text(String) in Jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append the image URL and some text in my chat feature but append some text in the image URL image is not open in chat. below is the my code.

```
var message = $(".typeappend").attr('href') + $(configData.selector + " #post_message").text().split(file_type_ex)[1];
```

details

```
$(".typeappend").attr('href') ="https://tfi-scorm.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/frame1.png" 

$(configData.selector + " #post_message").text().split(file_type_ex)[1] = " hi this is image for you"
```

Answer (score 0):

for image

```
var message = "<img src='" + $(".typeappend").attr('href') + "'>" + "<p>" + $(configData.selector + " #post_message").text().split(file_type_ex)[1] + "</p>";
```